# How to show the zero point of axis?

Tags: plotting

How to show the zero point of the crossing point between two axis  ?[image]

Comment: Add `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}` to the options for your plot.

Comment: AxesOrigin can only specify where any axes drawn should cross, it doesn't show the origin number.

Comment: @KarryMa, You can use the manual definition of `Ticks` to add your own ticks on the axis. Try `Ticks->{Table[i,{0,0.3,0.1}],Table[i,{0,0.3,0.1}]}`

Comment: Oh, I take it the graph in your question includes the point `(0, 0)` but it's simply not displaying the 0 tick mark labels?

Comment: Yeah,it has been solved,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {{0.01, 0.02}, {0.21, 0.12}, {0.41, 0.22}};

plotrange = {0, Max[#]} & /@ Transpose[data];

plot = ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> plotrange]
```

[image]

To change the zeros to "0" `FindTicks` can be used.  This includes a replacement to increase the tick height to 0.007 because otherwise they shrink a bit.  (No one knows why.)

```
ticks = Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}] @@@ plotrange /.
   {{0., 0} -> {0., "0"}, {0.005, 0.} -> {0.007, 0.}};

ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> plotrange, Ticks -> ticks]
```

[image]

Comment: Right, thank you!

Comment: No problem. BTW you could use `ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, Automatic}, {0, Automatic}}]`

Comment: Yeah,wise men seek more.